# Account vs Keypair

Tags: web3.js

When should one use `Account` and when should one use `Keypair` from `@solana/web3.js`?

As far as I take it there is not any difference between them except for the fact that `Keypair` provides extra methods for the derivation of secret key from a seed phrase.

But it's too slight thing to separate them. Thus, I would like someone to make the reason clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always use `Keypair`. Account is deprecated since v1.10.0

See https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Account.html

> [deprecated] since v1.10.0, please use Keypair instead.